# set State of Certain Checkbox in List, without influencing other tiles | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a ListView with Checkboxes

```
bool checked = false;
    ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: logs!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Log log = logs[index];
                      return ExpansionTile(
                              title: 
                                  Checkbox(
                                      value: checked,
                                      onChanged: (curValue) {
                                        checked = curValue;
                                        setState(() {});
                                      }),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                    },
                  );
```

The problem is that when I check one Box in the List, all values are changed, because the variable is global & therefore the same boolean is appended to all checkboxes.

When I pack the boolean inside the ListView, I cant click on the Checkbox at all -> because of the setState the value is always reseted & no change appears

So what can I do to make all Checkboxes clickable without influencing the click state of the other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only 1 variable to check the state of the checkbox, all other checkbox widgets will also depend on this checked variable.

You have to define for every checkbox a own "checked" variable, you could add a checked variable to the Log class and then query and set it each time.

```
Checkbox(
                value: logs[index].checked,
                onChanged: (curValue) {
                  logs[index].checked = curValue;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here using single variable for all items. You can use a List for selected item

```dart
  List<Log> selectedLogs  = [];
```

```dart
Checkbox(
    value: selectedLogs.contains(log),
    onChanged: (curValue) {
        if(selectedLogs.contains(log)){
        selectedLogs.remove(log);
        }else {
        selectedLogs.add(log);
        }
      setState(() {});
    }),
)
```